# VisualElements not shown on first load of page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visualtreehelper

I'm trying to update all my textbox elements after the load of my Page.

**The question**

> Why are the TextBoxes not returned on first load?

**Explaination**

> I have a MainWindow with a Frame element in it to navigate between wpf Pages.
>   So when a user click on a menu item, a page loads into the frame.
>   Here is the code when a user Click on a MenuItem:

**Code for loading new page into Frame (Method Navigate)**

```
    public static void Navigate(Page page, double fadeTime = 0.6)
    {
        MainWindow MainWin = (MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow;
        Frame NavFrame = MainWin.mainFrame;


        if (NavFrame.Content != page)
        {
            NavFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(page);

            //Gebruik Dispatcher om Fadein Effect te kunnen toepassen
            Frame mainFrame = NavFrame;
            NavFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    //Voeg Animatie Toe
                    NavFrame.Opacity = 0;
                    DoubleAnimation fadeIn = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(fadeTime), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
                    mainFrame.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeIn, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
                }));                

            //Bij navigeren naar andere pagina roep GC aan.
            GC.Collect();
        }

        int amount = 0;
        //Apply Color on CaretBrush
        foreach (TextBox tb in Worker.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(page))
        {
            amount++;
            tb.CaretBrush = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FF8E9CFF");
        }

        Worker.ShowModernBox(amount.ToString()); //Custom messagebox
        page.UpdateDefaultStyle();
        page.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

**The FindVisualChildren method**

```
 //Haal alle elementen van huidige view op.
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        //Indien het object gevuld is met componenten
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            //Voor ieder Object in huidige view
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                //geef Child terug
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T) child;
                }

                //geef CHilds van CHild terug.
                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Problem**

> The first Time a user loads this page, It returns the int amount as 0, when clicked a second time, i get all 19 textboxes returned. why is that? When I debug it and i Expand my page i can see the textboxes in there

Comment: The visual tree has simply not been created when the Page is navigated to the first time. However, why such a complicated approach? You might instead just bind all the TextBoxes' `CaretBrush` properties to a single view model property, or static resource or whatever, which you change when the page is navigated to.

Comment: `Navigate()` is asynchronous, so you should register to `LoadCompleted`.

Comment: Pragmateek, Thanks! did not work for the LoadCompleted but it did for ContentRendered on the Frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pragmateek.
**Solution: Binding the following code to the ContentRendered Event**

```
 foreach (TextBox tb in Worker.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(page))
    {
        amount++;
        tb.CaretBrush = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FF8E9CFF");
    }

    Worker.ShowModernBox(amount.ToString()); //Custom messagebox
    page.UpdateDefaultStyle();
    page.UpdateLayout();
```

**Reason**

> The content was simply not rendered when the visualTree was finding the elements. So wait for the page to render all of its contents first, by binding it to a ContentRendered Event.

credits go to Pragmateek